# IF/ELSEIF comparing variables from database

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, shopping-cart, discount

Hello I'm new to PHP.

So I have this query here that checks if `Order Total`'s `status` is set to 1 or 0 in the database

```
$chk_dscnt=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `discount` WHERE `discount_type` = 'Order Total'  ");
while ($x=mysql_fetch_array($chk_dscnt)) {
    echo $x['status'];
}
```

`(I already have a function to change the status to 1 or 0)`.

I would like to do a discount on the `$grand_total` if the `status` is 1 and display the normal `$grand_total` if the status is 0. But even if I set the `status` to 1 or 0 it always performs the `elseif statement` and displays the `undiscounted price` or the normal price.

Is there any logical or syntax error ?? need you help guys :)

```
if ($x == '1') 
{   
    $subt = 0;
        $discounted_price= $grand_total - ($grand_total*(5/100) );
        $subt= $subt + $discounted_price;
        echo '<input type=text name=total value='.$subt.'>';
}
else if($x == '0'){ 

     $subt =$grand_total; ;
        echo '<input type=text name=total value='.$subt.'>';

}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case `$x` is an array. so you can't compare array to a string like this

```
if ($x == '1')
```

you need to use the index to compare

```
if ($x['status'] == '1')
```